# linking problems with functions in libircclient

Tags: c, ubuntu

**problem is either way linking or including .... the library libircclient.h is been found but the functions which are used in the library not....**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/*#include "./libircclient-1.6/include/libircclient.h"*/ 
#include "libircclient.h"

typedef struct
{
    char    * channel;
    char    * nick;

} irc_ctx_t;


void addlog (const char * fmt, ...)
{
    FILE * fp;   // File-Zeiger
    char buf[1024];
    va_list va_alist; 

    va_start (va_alist, fmt); 
#if defined (WIN32)
    _vsnprintf (buf, sizeof(buf), fmt, va_alist);  
#else                                                         
    vsnprintf (buf, sizeof(buf), fmt, va_alist); 
#endif
    va_end (va_alist); 

    printf ("%s\n", buf);

    if ( (fp = fopen ("irctest.log", "ab")) != 0 ) // High level, daher File-Zeiger
    {
        fprintf (fp, "%s\n", buf);
        fclose (fp);
    }
}


void dump_event (irc_session_t * session, const char * event, const char * origin, const char ** params, unsigned int count)
{
    char buf[512];
    int cnt;

    buf[0] = '\0';

    for ( cnt = 0; cnt < count; cnt++ )
    {
        if ( cnt )
            strcat (buf, "|");

        strcat (buf, params[cnt]);
    }


    addlog ("Event \"%s\", origin: \"%s\", params: %d [%s]", event, origin ? origin : "NULL", cnt, buf);
}


void event_join (irc_session_t * session, const char * event, const char * origin, const char ** params, unsigned int count)
{
    dump_event (session, event, origin, params, count);
    irc_cmd_user_mode (session, "+i");
    irc_cmd_msg (session, params[0], "Hi all");
}


void event_connect (irc_session_t * session, const char * event, const char * origin, const char ** params, unsigned int count)
{
    irc_ctx_t * ctx = (irc_ctx_t *) irc_get_ctx (session);
    dump_event (session, event, origin, params, count);

    irc_cmd_join (session, ctx->channel, 0);
}


void event_privmsg (irc_session_t * session, const char * event, const char * origin, const char ** params, unsigned int count)
{
    dump_event (session, event, origin, params, count);

    printf ("'%s' said me (%s): %s\n", 
        origin ? origin : "someone",
        params[0], params[1] );
}

....
```

gcc irctest.c

> /tmp/ccbleNaD.o: In function `event_join': irctest.c:(.text+0x2b9):
>
> undefined reference to `irc_cmd_user_mode' irctest.c:(.text+0x2d4):
>
> undefined reference to `irc_cmd_msg' /tmp/ccbleNaD.o: In function
>
> `event_connect': irctest.c:(.text+0x2fe): undefined reference to
>
> `irc_get_ctx' irctest.c:(.text+0x33b): undefined reference to
>
> `irc_cmd_join' /tmp/ccbleNaD.o: In function`dcc_recv_callback':
>
> irctest.c:(.text+0x43c): undefined reference to `irc_dcc_msg'
>
> irctest.c:(.text+0x49b): undefined reference to `irc_dcc_msg'
>
> irctest.c:(.text+0x4a7): undefined reference to `irc_strerror' ....
>
> collect2: ld gab 1 als Ende-Status zurück

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you compile you have to link against the library. It is finding the function declarations but not able to link against the object files containing the definition.

I think it would be something like:
`gcc -lircclient irctest.c`

Comment: I ve done it before but then I got                                gcc -lircclient irctest.c
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lircclient
collect2: ld gab 1 als Ende-Status zurück
I ve got the libircclient.h in the same folder as the irctest.c

Comment: `libircclient.h` is just the header include, it doesn't have the compiled code from the library. Do you have a file named something like `libircclient.o` or `.so`? Where did you get this `libircclient`? You need to have the object file to link against and it appears as though it cannot be found.

Comment: thanks... that was my mistake... I always linked against libircclient.h instead of libircclient.o